# how to prove that the following set is closed?

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove this set is closed in $R^2$.

$C=\{0\times0\} U\{e^t\cos t\times{e^t\sin t}|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: No offense meant, but your definition is grammatical nonsense... Do you mean $C=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(e^t\cos(t),e^t\sin(t))\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$? Also, **hint:** to prove that a set is closed, you can either take a point in its complement and show that it has an open neighborhood not intersecting the set, or you can show that every convergent sequence in the set converges to a point in the set (I'm not sure that this works in general, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is nice enough).

Comment: Ok, I checked. It is always true that a subset $C$ of a topological space is closed if, and only if it contains all of its accumulation points. Moreover, if the space $X$ is 1st countable, then an accumulation point of $C$ is necessarily the limit of a sequence in $C$. This is obviously the case for $X=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Daniel, in order to show a subset of a metric space is closed, it's enough to show limits of sequences in $A$ are in $A$.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in your set $A$, which converges in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $a_n \to (0,0)$ we are done since $(0,0) \in A$.

So assume $a_n \to (x,y)$ where $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. By taking $\epsilon$ small enough, we get that from some point in the sequence, all the elements are different from $(0,0)$.

So, since a limit of a sequence depends only on it's tail, we can assume $a_n \neq (0,0)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

i.e we suppose that $a_n=(e^{t_n}\cos(t_n),e^{t_n}\sin(t_n))$ converges to $(x,y)$. Then $$e^{2t_n}=(e^{t_n})^2 \to x^2+y^2 > 0$$

So $t_n \to \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)=b$ so (by continuity of $e^x,\sin(x),\cos(x)$ $a_n \to (e^b\cos(b),e^{b}\sin(b)) \in A$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

For another approach, you can show that the complement is open:

if $(x,y)\in C^c$, then $\forall t\in \mathbb R,\ (x,y)\neq (e^t\cos t,\ {e^t\sin t})$ so one of $x\neq e^t\cos t$ or $y\neq e^t\sin t$ must be true. Wlog the former.

Then, using continuity of the components, find an $\epsilon $ such that for all $t\in \mathbb R$

$\vert x-e^t\cos t\vert >\epsilon $.

Since $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ there is also an $\epsilon _1>0$ such that $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}>\epsilon _1$.

Now to finish, we take $B_{(\min \left \{ (\epsilon , \epsilon _1)\right \})/2}(x,y)$, and find that $B\cap C=\emptyset$.